# How to proxy another page in PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I'm looking for the fastest and easiest way to proxy a page in PHP. I don't want the user to be redirected, I just want my script to return the same content, response code and headers as another remote URL.

Comment: Can we have more details, I mean, what if the actual response code of the remote url to be accessed is 302 ? Should the script handle the redirection or just pass the status code with the new url ?

Comment: Ideally it would return something 100% identical as if you went to the original URL. For my project, I don't really need that much level of details and the file_get_contents seems to do the job. But I still think it's an interesting question

Comment: If you proxy a HTML page you will run into problems if for instance the page contains images and the URL to the images are relative (and not absolute, i.e. start with http://...) because the browser will try to retrieve the images using the absolute path which point to the proxy-server - but probably not to the proxy-code unless you have made a real proxy server and it handles images, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`echo file_get_contents('proxypage');` 
Would that work?

**EDIT:**

First answer was a bit short, and I don't believe it will handle headers as you would like.

However you can also do this:

```
function get_proxy_site_page( $url )
{
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,     // return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $remoteSite = curl_exec($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $header['content'] = $remoteSite;
    return $header;
}
```

This will return you an array containing lots of information on the remote page. `$header['content']`  will have both the content of the website and the headers, `$header[header_size]` will contain the length of that header so you can use `substr` to split those up.

Then it's just a matter of using `echo`and `header` to proxy the page.

Comment: use everytihng but not curl. It sux in the currently implementation

Answer (score 6):

You can use the PHP cURL functions to achieve this functionality:

http://www.php.net/curl

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$urlContent = curl_exec($ch);
```

From this point, you would grab the response header information using http://www.php.net/curl-getinfo. (There are several values you can grab, all listed in the documentation).

```
// Check if any error occured
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    header('Content-Type: '.$info['content_type']);
    echo $urlContent;
}
```

Make sure to close out the cURL handle.

```
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Typo for CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER.
However this seems to print the HTTP headers in the body of the response.

Comment: Try changing CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 (I've edited the code) to prevent the headers from being outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html of the next page with curl, and then echo the response.