# Open external domain URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, url, html

I would like to know a similar code to show an external domain URL into div using Jquery. I know I need to use Json, but I can't find a clear example to do exactly what the below code does.

```
<div id="external"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#external").load("http://www.domain.com/file.php?param=option");});</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use JSON? Are you just trying to load the content of the PHP script into the #external div?

Comment: Why is the way you showed not suitable?

Comment: @KayKay because it gets stopped by the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't .load html with a jsonp datatype. It doesn't work that way.

The JSONP datatype would require that your external url returns valid JSONP. `JSONP != HTML`.

JSONP can contain HTML, however the external url would have to return it in that format. If you have no control over the external url, there isn't much you can do other than having your server get the html, or using an iframe.

Comment: @refhat that's the problem. there is no jsonp data.

Answer (score 0):

Your script uses ajax to load the content from `http://www.domain.com/file.php?param=option` and puts this in div with id `#external`

If you want to open a URL then you should use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) attribute on a tag and set this to the link you want to open.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. I think you're right, but, sorry, I did not understand your reply. Could you please help me?

Comment: With this method can i open a URL into a div?

Comment: what do you mean by opening url in a div. url has to be opened in a link. Your div can load the content from that  url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a cross domain Ajax call like this without either using a proxy page or jsonp. Trying to do this with ajax is a violation of the same origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. Proxy page in my opinion is the easist solution. Basically create a page in php, coldfusion, or whatever web language your using that does a get on the URL you want to load. Once you have that you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://YOURSITE/YOURPROXYPAGE.cfm',
    type: 'GET',
    data : {param1 : 'something', param2 :'other'}
    success : function(data){
        $('#external').html(data);
    },
    error : function(x,t,e){
        console.log(x);
        console.log(t);
        console.log(e);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

**EDIT 1:**
Notice I added a data field above. This data field will be an object of data we want to pass to the page we're sending the ajax request to. The on the ajax proxy page we can pull the ajax data params as query params.

Additionally you could change the type to a `POST` then the data would be posted over as if by a form to the proxy page we're requesting.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm not a php guy, but I threw php proxy page in the googlez and found some possible solutions. You can try this: [How to proxy another page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425666/how-to-proxy-another-page-in-php)

Again, I'm not a php guy so there could be other better ways but to pull query params you can try: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Hello, ShortRound. The problem is that the URL I want to load has several parameters choosen by the user (like a built widget), understand? Is it possible to use your example even in that situation? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. I did not understand yet how sould look the PHP page that will do a get. :-(